# jetty threads increasing linearly

Tags: java, solr, jetty, newrelic, lucidworks

All I have got an apache FUSION server and configured jetty for the same.
I can see using newrelic that the count of threads is increasing linearly. After a time these threads are increased to a limit and cause out of memory exception until I restart my proxy server.

[image]

Please find below the start.ini configs I did to regulate the number of threads.

```
--module=server
jetty.threadPool.minThreads=10
jetty.threadPool.maxThreads=150
jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout=5000
jetty.server.dumpAfterStart=false
jetty.server.dumpBeforeStop=false
jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize=32768
etc/jetty-stop-timeout.xml
--module=continuation
--module=deploy
--module=jsp
--module=ext
--module=resources
--module=client
--module=annotations
--module=servlets
etc/jetty-logging.xml
--module=jmx
--module=stats
```

I tried adding thread enabled property too but it didn't work. Can anyone help how can I limit these threads? For the same configurations on other servers, I can see the threads are not increasing and are well in range on newrelic.

Comment: You mean lucidworks Fusion?

Comment: Yes Winnie it is lucidworks fusion and I am facing issue with threads in proxy.

Comment: You probably need to start from seeing what these threads are actually doing. Do you already have collections and data on your Fusion server?

Comment: Yes its an existing setup data and everything is there. Maybe I am missing some configuration. The same setup is working on other server.

Comment: Are you able to perform search when the server is up? May be the shards are still recovering which are usually memory intensive. Like suggested, you need to start by looking at processes that are eating up the resources.

Comment: `--module=continuation` is super old and deprecated, and probably means you are using [an old, possibly unsupported, version of Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html).

Comment: Yes Winnie as far as I can see the fusion-proxy is the one eating up all the resources as its growing its threads endlessly.

Comment: That's too abstract to know what's going on. What does the logs say? Are you seeing OOM exception in the logs? There should be some clues.